# Convert function to exploit parallelization of the GPU

Tags: pytorch, numba

I have a function that uses values stored in one array to operate on another array.  This behaves similar to the numpy.hist function.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def array_func(x, y, output_counts, output_weights):
    for row in range(x.size):
        col = int(x[row] * 10)
        output_counts[col] += 1
        output_weights[col] += y[row]

    return (output_counts, output_weights)

# in the current code these arrays exists ad pytorch tensors
# on the GPU and get converted to numpy arrays on the CPU before 
# being passed to "array_func"
x = np.random.randint(0, 11, (1000)) / 10
y = np.random.randint(0, 100, (10000))

output_counts, output_weights = array_func(x, y, np.zeros(y.size), np.zeros(y.size))
```

While this works for arrays it does not work for torch tensors that are on the GPU.  This is close to what `histogram` functions do, but I also need the summation of binned values (i.e., the `output_weights` array/tensor).  The current function requires me to continually pass the data from GPU to CPU, followed by the CPU function being run in series.

Can this function be converted to run in parallel on the GPU?

##**EDIT**##

The challenge is caused by the following line:

```
output_weights[col] += y[row]
```

If it weren't for that line I could just use the `torch.histc` function.

Here's my thought: GPUs are "fast" because they have hundreds/thousands of threads available and can run parts of a big job (or many smaller jobs) on these threads.  However, if I convert the function above to work on torch tensors then there is no benefit to running on the GPU (it actually kills the performance).  I wonder if there is a way I can break of `x` so each value gets sent to different threads (similar to how `apply_async` does within `multiprocessing`)?

I'm open to other options.

In it's current form the function is fast, but the GPU-to-CPU data transfer is killing me.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks for the nudge.  I updated the imports and included an example of how the function is used.

Comment: The size is far too small for the GPU to be useful. Is this realistic size? Data matter a lot for histogram computation since the indirection and parallel algorithms change regarding the input (both size and content).

Comment: @JérômeRichard No, this is not the real size of the arrays/tensors; just an MWE.

Comment: Ok, so what is the actual sizes (estimation) and what is data distribution? (eg. uniform, normal, unknown). Regarding the case, the algorithm change and in some cases there are no way to parallelize the computation efficiently. There is no generic method that "just works".

Comment: @JérômeRichard The actual size of 'x' is variable, but 1E6 is a good estimate.  The distribution is unknown.  I don't think this is relevant though.  The index is of the 'output' arrays is determined by the value in 'x[row]'.  If I just wanted the counts per bin then the histogram function would work perfectly...but I also need the sum of all weights within each bin.  I don't think I can get away from the 'for' loop so I wonder if this can be made to run parallel or not.  Please see edit for update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is indeed a general histogram operation. There are multiple ways to compute this on a GPU regarding the number of items to scan, the size of the histogram and the distribution of the values.

For example, one solution consist in building local histograms in each separate kernel blocks and then perform a reduction. However, this solution is not well suited in your case since `len(x) / len(y)` is relatively small.

An alternative solution is to perform **atomic updates** of the histogram in parallel. This solutions only *scale* well if there is no atomic *conflicts* which is dependent of the actual input data. Indeed, if all value of `x` are equal, then all updates will be serialized which is slower than doing the accumulation sequentially on a CPU (due to the overhead of the atomic operations). Such a case is frequent on small histograms but assuming the distribution is close to uniform, this can be fine.

This operation can be done with Numba using CUDA (targetting Nvidia GPUs). Here is an example of kernel solving your problem:

```py
@cuda.jit
def array_func(x, y, output_counts, output_weights):
    tx = cuda.threadIdx.x  # Thread id in a 1D block
    ty = cuda.blockIdx.x   # Block id in a 1D grid
    bw = cuda.blockDim.x   # Block width, i.e. number of threads per block
    pos = tx + ty * bw     # Compute flattened index inside the array
    if pos < x.size:
        col = int(x[pos] * 10)
        cuda.atomic.add(output_counts, col, 1)
        cuda.atomic.add(output_weights, col, y[pos])
```

For more information about how to run this kernel, please read the [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/kernels.html). Note that the arrays `output_counts` and `output_weights` can possibly be directly created on the GPU so to avoid transfers. `x` and `y` should be on the GPU for better performance (otherwise a CPU reduction will be certainly faster). Also note that the kernel should be pretty fast so the overhead to run/wait it and allocate/free temporary array may be significant and even possibly slower than the kernel itself (but certainly faster than doing a double transfer from/to the CPU so to compute things on the CPU assuming data was on the GPU). Note also that such atomic accesses are only fast on quite recent Nvidia GPU that benefit from specific computing units for atomic operations.